# Conditional formatting: cell is zero and not empty

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I want to highlight all cells in my sheet which are zero but not empty.
I tried this (and some others) and none worked. Without `AND` they are working.

```
=AND(
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()))<>"";
 INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW();COLUMN()))=0)
)
```

Comment: Try `=AND(A1<>"";A1=0)` with your Applies To: for the whole sheet.

Comment: well it worked (I don't get it but who cares) - post it as an answer | everytime I read it I thought it was working for their special problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for IDIRECT and ADDRESS.  Base the formula on the upper left cell and Excel will change the relative references to the correct address:

```
=AND(A1<>"";A1=0)
```

Comment: do you know how it would work with `INDIRECT`?

Comment: INDIRECT and ADDRESS are volatile and you want to avoid using them when ever possible.  I frankly do not see a problem with your formula, but it may take time for each change as each change does not just recalculate the one cell that changed but the entire sheet of formulas, that is a lot of calculations and will slow down the calculation times.